# Calling override of virtual function is causing a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, overriding, header-files, virtual

I am trying to override a function but end up with a segmentation fault. I followed some Tutorials and now I'am not able to find the origin of the segmentation fault.

I use 1 header and 1 cpp file. **Update** The Reason is that I want to Make multiple Command like print and instatiate different commands and call the Execute method without knowing what exactly command this is.

This is declared in one header File :

```
  class Command{
    public:
     virtual int Execute(std::stack<NumericData>* stack)=0;
  };

  class Print : public Command{
    public:
     int Execute(std::stack<NumericData>* stack);
  };
```

This is the implementation one cpp file:

```
 ... // inside some function
    std::stack<NumericData> stack;
    Command* command;
    if(1){                         // if is updated
        Print print;               // and reason for seg fault
        command=&print;            // without if it works
    }
    command->Execute(&stack); // <- segmentation fault
    ...

    int Command::Execute(std::stack<NumericData>* stack){
          printf("Execute parent\n");
          return 0; 
    }

    int Print::Execute(std::stack<NumericData>* stack){
          printf("Execute child\n");
          return 1;
    }
```

Comment: If `Command::Execute` is pure virtual, why are you defining it?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @cigien , i want multiple commands that inherit from the Command class and implement different execute functions so that i can have different command and i dont need to know exactly which one it is i can use the execute method to execute the command

Comment: Please add this information to the question, and see @churill 's comment about making an mre.

Comment: working on an mre

Comment: updated the question, the problem is with the if which i did not bring up in the first place

Comment: i see, so i have to allocate memory to keep the object in memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not related to your virtual functions, or to the override. It is simply that you are using the address of an object that no longer exists.

In the following code block:

```cpp
    Command* command;
    if(1){                         // if is updated
        Print print;               // and reason for seg fault
        command=&print;            // without if it works
    }
    command->Execute(&stack); // <- segmentation fault
```

the lifetime of the `print` variable is restricted to its enclosing scope (the `{ ...}`). Thus, the address you assign to `command` is no longer valid when you have left that scope, and your `command->Execute(&stack);` line is attempting to dereference a pointer to an object that no longer exists, causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: thank you, should i change to questions title to avoid confusion ?

Comment: @Thegabagabor I changed the title, but maybe you want to change the change?

Comment: thank you, i dont realy know what a good title is so i would just leave it like it is now